# How Hector Autonomous Rescue Robot Detect QRCodes?

Tags: slam, navigation, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I am using Hector_slam package for mapping and marking objects and Now I need to add QRcodes Detection to it.

anyone knows How can i do this job with darmstadt Ros packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64696/how-hector-autonomous-rescue-robot-detect-qrcodes?/) by [Messi](https://answers.ros.org/users/5076/messi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently you can't, as we have not released our packages used for QR code detection yet. The underlying semantic worldmodel is released however, see the [hector_object_tracker](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_object_tracker) package. More detailed documentation is in the works, but will not be available till after RoboCup due to time constraints.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2013-09-14**:
The hector_qrcode_detection package which we also use for RoboCup is available in the hector_vision stack now: https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision .